# Add ending slash to <input ... > , so it would look like this <input ... />

Tags: regex, shell, sed

I need to add ending slash to all input tags that are missing this. So instead of

```
<input id="1" class="hello">
```

I would get:

```
<input id="1" class="hello" />
```

How can I do this using sed or some other bash tool?

Comment: If you do this blindly, you will run into cases where you're orphaning closing tags. For example, <tag></tag> would become <tag/></tag> which isn't what you want. Watch out!

Comment: Not mine but it do its job $selfClosing = array('br', 'hr', 'input');
$value = preg_replace_callback(sprintf('#<(?:%s).*?>#i', implode('|',$selfClosing)), function ($match) {
    return preg_replace('#(?<!/)>$#', ' />', $match[0]);
}, $input);

Answer (score 5):

It is not recommended to parse and substitute HTML using regex. But if you want a quick shell-based solution, the following sed command should work:

```
sed '/<input /s#\([^/]\)>#\1/>#' file
```

This will place `/` only if `>` is not already preceded by a slash.

**PS:** Keep in mind that your HTML input tag should be completely in one line.

Comment: +1 but better add `<input` match part in sed line. OP just wants to change input tags.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
sed '/<input/s,[^/]>$,"/>,' file
```

Comment: I almost pressed +1.. `\/&` is correct? `">` would be `/">` right?

Comment: @Kent You're right no need to escape `/` in replacement part. I didn't follow the second suggestion? Can you elaborate on it please?

Comment: oh, sorry, when I read my comment again, it is really hard to understand. :D ... what I meant, if in inputfile there was `<input foo="bar">`, your line would change it into `<input foo="bar/">` which is not correct.  so my original comment should be `is replacement part \/& correct? "> would be replaced by /">?`

Comment: @Kent Yep, you're right. Fixed the answer. You're feedback is always great to get so no biggie. :)

Comment: first I would say that sed is really not the right tool to do this task. that's why I didn't post answer. your fix works for `foo="bar">` case, but if we read your sed line, replace non-slash + ending > with double quote+slash+>. so all single non-slash -> double quote. how about `f="b" >`?  a regex group here would be better. in fact the other answer could fail too, apart from the `<input` part. anyway +1, it works for the line in question.